# i am getting an error in FirebasePlugin.java, how to solve it?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

when i fire a command  ionic build android  on terminal.
it show following error.

```
BUILD FAILED


Total time: 7.557 secs

Error: /Users/mac2/Desktop/myProj/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: /Users/mac2/Desktop/myProj/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java:389: error: cannot find symbol
                mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(cordova.getActivity(), name, null);
                                  ^
symbol:   method setCurrentScreen(Activity,String,<null>)
location: variable mFirebaseAnalytics of type FirebaseAnalytics
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

below is the code in FirebasePlugin.java

```
private void setScreenName(final CallbackContext callbackContext, final String name) {
    // This must be called on the main thread
    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(cordova.getActivity(), name, null);
                callbackContext.success();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I dont understand why such error occured in this file.

I try to solve, but i could not.

Can anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: did you solve the problem ?

Comment: @dafriskymonkey no